# Running the wolframscript on linux then it returns permission denied

Tags: scripting

I use the script from mathematica's tutorial

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

(* generate "num" samples of a mixed distribution *) 
num  = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[2]]];
Print /@ RandomVariate[
  MixtureDistribution[ 
    {1, 2},
    {NormalDistribution[1, 0.2],
     NormalDistribution[3, 0.1]}
  ], num,  WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

then save this script as file.wls, and make the script executable

```
chmod a+x file.wls
```

but when run the script `./file.wls 10` , it returns

```
-bash: ./file.wls: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

so what's happening there? is this problem due to my computer?

Comment: You may need to do `which wolframscript` and then `chmod +x` on that executable as well...

Comment: wolframscript is already executable

Comment: You could also replace the hashbang with the direct path to wolframscript? Does `env wolframscript` give you the same error?

Comment: Direct path to wolframscript also give the same error information, but ```env wolframscript``` works well.